# How to share Vertex data between scenes in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js

In THREE.js what is the best way to share vertex data across two or more different Scenes?
My goal is to avoid copying the same data to GPU memory as well as reduce GPU memory footprint.
(The scenes are rendered in different WebGL renderers.)

Should I use the same THREE.BufferGeometry objects in the scenes?
What is the relation between THREE.BufferGeometry, THREE.Float32BufferAttribute and actual VBOs?
What if the mesh has the same vertex positions but different colors - is there any option to reuse just the positions data and provide different colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The scenes are rendered in different WebGL renderers.

In this case it's not possible what you are looking for. Each instance of `WebGLRenderer` has its own WebGL rendering context. It's not possible share resources like WebGL buffer data across different contexts.

So even if you share an instance of `BufferGeometry`, the renderers will create own internal [WebGLBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLBuffer) objects for this geometry since there is no way around it.

> What is the relation between THREE.BufferGeometry, THREE.Float32BufferAttribute and actual VBOs?

`THREE.BufferGeometry` represents the entire geometry data for a single 3D object. Buffer attributes are representations of VBOs.

> What if the mesh has the same vertex positions but different colors - is there any option to reuse just the positions data and provide different colors?

You can reuse buffer attributes for different geometries. However, this has no effect when using multiple renderers.

`three.js R107`

Comment: Thank you! Is it true that Buffer Attributes represent VBOs, but actually THREE.BufferGeometry is the object that controls the life-cycle of the VBOs? I assume this, because Buffer Attributes are not disposable.

Comment: Yes, buffer attributes are not disposable. So the life-cycle is controlled by `BufferGeometry`. If you are going to dispose an instance of `BufferGeometry`, all related attributes are removed (meaning the respective `WebGLBuffer`s are deleted).